# Display SOQL info on VF page

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, controller

I have a custom VFpage that I am trying to display the current users SmallPhotoUrl. I have the SOQL working correctly but the issue is when I go to display the image. I am not sure how to craft the output without putting it inside of a PageBlockTable, which screws up the entire format of the page.

```
<apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!AccPhoto}" var="c">
  <div class="topbar">
    <ul class="dropdown">
      <li id="main">
      <apex:image value="{!c.Team_Member__r.SmallPhotoUrl}" />
      <apex:outputLink value="{!name}" styleClass="bf">{!name}</apex:outputLink>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

The part of the controller that is used for this section is,

```
public String name;
public id uuid, actid;

public personInfo() {
    this.uuid = UserInfo.getUserid();
    this.name = [select name from user where id = :uuid][0].name;
    this.actid = [select accountid from user where id = :uuid][0].accountid;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public ApexPages.StandardSetController setAccPhoto {
    get {
        if(setAccPhoto == null) {
            setAccPhoto = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(
            [Select Team_Member__r.SmallPhotoUrl From Account_Team__c a where account__r.id = :actid])); 
        }
        return setAccPhoto;
    }
    set;
}

public List<Account_Team__c> getAccPhoto() {
    return (List<account_team__c>) setAccPhoto.getrecords();
}
```

How do I display the photo without having to use a PageBlock?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `<apex:pageBlockTable>` use an `<apex:repeat>`.

Also, ensure the image you are trying to display isn't a blank value.

Comment: Do you see any reason why the image would not be displayed? That does fix everything else on the page though.

Comment: Does the photo show when you had it as a pageBlockTable but not repeat?  Or does it now show for either one?

Comment: Does not show for either... Am I thinking about the issue incorrectly?

Comment: Well, what does display?  Is it just blank, or is there some text or something there?

Comment: Nothing displays. But when I would commit out the pageBlockTable and img it would display the page like it should. That is why I thought it was the page block.

Comment: Is there any chance that field doesn't have a value?  Have you confirmed that it is 100% sure not a blank field?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13275/discussion-between-dphil-and-adroidman)